# changing the URL, when opening a modal window, possibility to enter a modal window after the url Bootstrap 3 / AngularJS / CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

I need create modal window with option, that when u open modal window, url is changing for example if u click a href with #123 in url will be after slash #123, and If I want to send someone link to modal window, he will redirect to this modal window after url. Can someone explain me how can I make it?:)

Because at this moment is that when u click some link, url does not change.

I use to modal window bootstrap 3 here is everything what I use in my project :

**demo with whole code**

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/rYeXvV

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{$index}}">Launch demo {{$index}}modal</a>
```

BTW
I also using AngularJS if it will help somehow to create this option.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following service:

https://github.com/garakh/ngSilent

It allows you to change the URL and/or add parameters in the URL without calling the related route and controller. So before opening the modal window, you could use this service to add what you want to the URL.

Note that I have no connection to the developer, I have just used it in the past and it worked well for a similar problem.

Comment: there's no other way? because normally after click a href to modal url is changing, but here I use bootstrap 3 modal and I think, this changing url is blocked by bootstrap, we can't unblock it?

Comment: Bootstrap shouldn't be blocking anything. Modals are just divs hidden on the same page, or appended to the page via JS. When sites add ids and such to the URL when a modal is opened, they are typically either: a), using the html5 `pushState` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), or b) setting some fragment identifier using `window.location.hash. AFAIK, changing the URL when opening a modal is not default behaviour.

Comment: loook if you add into ur project     <a href="#add">Add</a> try click it, your url will be change, but if U add bootstrap3 and jquery, later add this code ->  <a href="#myModal"  data-toggle="modal"></a> and when u try click it, url will not change, so bootstrap must block it somehow, what do you think?